# Cómo desactivar la generación de ficheros *.itrace en el servidor de compilación

Tags: visual-studio, servidor, deployment

Tenemos un servidor TFS 2012 que compila todas nuestras soluciones y que al ejecutar los UnitTests, hemos detectado 2 casos en los que al ejecutar dichos tests y sólo cuando el resultado es fallido, se generan ficheros *.itrace en la carpeta C:\Windows\Temp. Esos tests ejecutan elementos externos, (uno un ejecutable y el otro uno o varios powershells). Estos ficheros iTrace tienen, como primera parte del nombre del fichero, el nombre de los ejecutables que los generan.

En los builds de TFS tenemos configurado que usen los ficheros de configuracion (runsettings) de cada solución para ejecutar los tests, y todos incluyen el DataCollector de CodeCoverage configurado.

Lo que hemos detectado, es que al eliminar el fichero de runsettings, los tests no generan los ficheros itrace.

Este es el contenido del fichero runsettings de una de las soluciones que tenemos (En la seccion exclude he borrado el contenido y lo he sustituido por puntos suspensivos):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations that affect the Test Framework -->
  <RunConfiguration>
    <!-- Path relative to solution directory -->
    <ResultsDirectory>.\TestResults</ResultsDirectory>

    <!-- [x86] | x64  
      - You can also change it from menu Test, Test Settings, Default Processor Architecture -->
    <TargetPlatform>x64</TargetPlatform>

    <!-- Framework35 | [Framework40] | Framework45 -->
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>Framework40</TargetFrameworkVersion>
  </RunConfiguration>

  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
              <!--
                .*      matches a string of any characters
                \.      matches a dot "."
                \( \)   matches parentheses "( )"
                \\      matches a file path delimiter "\"
                ^       matches the start of the string
                $       matches the end of the string
               -->
            <ModulePaths>
                <Include>
                    <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
                    <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>
                </Include>
                <Exclude>
        ...
                </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>

  <!-- Adapter Specific sections -->

  <!-- MSTest adapter -->
  <MSTest>
    <MapInconclusiveToFailed>True</MapInconclusiveToFailed>
    <CaptureTraceOutput>false</CaptureTraceOutput>
    <DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>False</DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete>
    <DeploymentEnabled>False</DeploymentEnabled>
  </MSTest>
```

Dado que se generan múltiples ficheros de tamaño considerable en cada ejecución de cada build, y ocupan mucho espacio en disco nos surge la necesidad de desactivar la generación de los mismos.

De que forma genérica (preferiblemente) se podria hacer esto? Estos ficheros no son útiles en el servidor de TFS.

En caso de que no se pueda hacer de manera genérica, hay que incluir algun setting o modificar el contenido de los ficheros de runsettings de alguna forma para que los ficheros no se generen?

[Link a la misma pregunta en MSDN](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/2ee2dd9a-f4d5-4804-91e0-b845c3aba908/cmo-desactivar-la-generacin-de-ficheros-itrace-en-el-servidor-de-compilacin?forum=vstses)

Comment: Creo que poniendo `DeleteDeploymentDirectoryAfterTestRunIsComplete` en `True` deberia ser suficiente .Pero como actualmente no tengo un TFS no puedo comprobarlo

Comment: Gracias por tu aportacion! Hemos probado a cambiar este setting, pero no ha habido diferencia ( probablemente por que utilizamos XUnit y NUnit como test runners ). Sabemos que el hecho de tener la sección de DataCollectionRunSettings hace que se generen dichos ficheros, pero no podemos eliminarla por que es necesario para obtener los datos de code coverage.